# No redirect after processing login data

Tags: php

My page is not being redirected to `login_success2.php` page. Instead I am getting redirected to the same page.
My database name is `society123`, table name `member`, and column name is `email` and `password` respectively for email id and password respectively.
Can anyone help me out with this???

```
session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "society123";
try {      
    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);
    $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $eid = $_POST["eid"];
        $pass = $_POST["pass"];

        if (empty($_POST["eid"]) || empty($_POST["pass"])) {
            echo "all fields are required";
        } else {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM member where email = $eid AND password = $pass";
            $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
            $statement->execute(
                array(
                    'email' => $_POST["eid"],
                    'password' => $_POST["pass"]  
                )
            );
            $count = $statement->rowCount();
            if ($count > o) {
                $_SESSION["email"] = $_POST["eid"];
                header("location:login_success2.php");
            } else {
                echo "wrong data";
            }
        }
    }
} catch(PDOException $error) {
    $error->getMessage();
}
```

login_success2.php code:

```
//login_success2.php  
session_start();  
if (isset($_SESSION["email"])) {  
    echo '<h3>Login Success, Welcome - '.$_SESSION["eid"].'</h3>';  
    echo '<br /><br /><a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';  
} else {  
    header("location:pdo_login.php");  
}
```

Comment: What makes good developers is a good code editor and pretty code formatting. Once you do that, you will most likely realize your problem.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `var_dump()` is your friend. If the answers didn't help you solve the issue please update your question with additional information. Did you get new errors? What is the outcome of `execute` statement? What is the value of `$count` variable?

Comment: User passwords should ***NEVER*** be stored in plain text form, only as a hash. PHP has got functions for dealing with the hashing of passwords

Answer (score 0):

This will never succeed:

```
if($count > o){
```

You have an "o" instead of 0

```
if($count > 0){
```

so the session variable is never set.

*You could have diagnosed this far easier by removing the redirect with a dump of the session variable, to see that it was unset. Honestly I'm surprised this runs at all...

Comment: With proper error reporting this should be obvious that the OP wouldn't need to ask this question.

Comment: @William_Wilson thanks for noticing the mistake , i change the 'o' with zero as it should have but still nothing has changed

Comment: If the error reporting is suppressed (or logged to the file) then the `o` is treated as a string literal. Comparing integer with a string literal is perfectly valid on PHP.

Comment: @Dharman well that all is fine but what about my code its still not redirecting me and i am not able to understand why can you help me out with this,i need this for my project.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `$count` error William pointed out (you're checking for `o` instead of `0`), you'll want to re-examine [PHP's documentation on PDO:Prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with named parameters. Your placeholders in `$query` should use colons (`:email`, `:password`) and not the actual PHP variables with dollar signs (`$email`, etc).

The documentation also points out that you can use question marks instead of named parameters, which could be less confusing in this situation.

Comment: it still didn't work out i change $eid and $pass to :eid and :pass but still i am stuck on the same page

Comment: @nilesh Change it to `:email` and `:password`.